# Getting a value from an array without a key from php to Android

Tags: php, android

I’m trying to transfer data from php to Android. I use JSON to make send the array that has keys through the Http response and then parse it at the Android side.

This is PHP side:

```
<?php
$array=array("key1"=>"value1","key2"=>"value2");
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Android side:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.toString());
String value1 = object.getString("key1");
String value2 = object.getString("key2");
```

But what if I want to get data from array that has no key-pairs. How to do that?
I hope that was clear enough. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Every array has keys, no matter if they are associative or numeric

Comment: Your PHP code is invalid and will terminate with errors.

Comment: @RoyalBg Ok could you please explain further with an example. That would be more helpful.

Comment: See the examples [in　the PHPmanual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) Particularly, look into example 4 - **Example #4 Indexed arrays without key**

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen What is the matter with it?

Comment: Json is a key pair string, if you want to use Json, then it has to be that way.

Comment: @MansourFahad Run it and read the error messages. The `{...}` part is not valid PHP syntax.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen  I fixed it now. Thank you. I missed that. Anyway my question is still up.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray(/*define your response string here*/);
 ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
 for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
  valueList.add(((JSONObject)responseArray.get(i)).getString(/*define your key here*/));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but it it little lengthy...

You can separate it by calling method split.

**String strMainData = response.toString();**

Then split it in array like **String ArrayOfData[] = strMainData.split(",");**

Now you will have here each value in separate index of array and you can use anytime...